# .ToList() in MVC api Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, interface-implementation

maybe this asked before, but don't get a good answer.
I create a mvc API in mvc Core 2 then implement my interface,  in Get all Method when I want get list of All Customers get this error, in below show my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Dates.Api.Contacts;
using Dates.Model;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;

public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
      return  _db.Customer.ToList();
    }
```

> 'Customer' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT**: Customer is as class for code first in another project in the same solution,

***UPDATE TWO***:  the first think was my mistake for use Customer without DbSet :) but when use it get this error:

> The type 'IQueryable<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>    I open myproject.API.csproj and these are my dependency

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Core" Version="3.5.21022.801" />
```

Comment: how is `Customer` defined on your db context?

Comment: Can you show the line in your `DbContext` that contains the `Customer` property?

Comment: I would still like to see your code first code. If `_db.Customer` is indeed `DbSet<Customer>` it should work.

Comment: before second update I added system.core ver 3.... and after use DbSet<T> got this error, :, remove it again work down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Customer` is a subclass of `DBSet<T>` then I believe in `EF6` there is only an async to list method, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx)

Generally, blocking a thread in a synchronous call to IO is not a good practice, so it is best to use `async/await`

So you could do

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetAll()
{
    return await _db.Customer.ToListAsync();
}
```

But that would, of course change your method signature